# Organic Group, og details block link in lightbox

Tags: drupal-6, popup, overlay, lightbox2, organic-groups

I have used organic grouop(og) in my website, and i have a block of group details where group content creation link are appearing. now i want to open those link in lightbox. or in popup how can we do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the popup API - http://drupal.org/project/popups
or
Thickbox - http://drupal.org/project/thickbox